# Performance - FunctionCall vs Event vs Action vs Delegate

Tags: c#, performance, events, dependency-injection, delegates

Currently I am using Microsoft Sync Framework to synchronize databases. I need to gather information per record which is inserted/updated/deleted by Microsoft Sync Framework and do something with this information.

The sync speed can go over 50.000 records per minute. So that means my additional code need to be very lightweight otherwise it will be a huge performance penalty.

Microsoft Sync Framework raises an `SyncProgress` event for each record. I am subscribed to that code like this:

```
// Assembly1
SyncProvider.SyncProgress += OnSyncProgress;
// ....
private void OnSyncProgress(object sender, DbSyncProgressEventArgs e)
{
    switch (args.Stage)
    {
        case DbSyncStage.ApplyingInserts:
            // MethodCall/Delegate/Action<>/EventHandler<> => HandleInsertedRecordInformation 
            // Do something with inserted record info
            break;
        case DbSyncStage.ApplyingUpdates:
            // MethodCall/Delegate/Action<>/EventHandler<> => HandleUpdatedRecordInformation  
            // Do something with updated record info
            break;
        case DbSyncStage.ApplyingDeletes:
            // MethodCall/Delegate/Action<>/EventHandler<> => HandleDeletedRecordInformation
            // Do something with deleted record info
            break;
    }
}
```

Somewhere else in another assembly I have three methods:

```
// Assembly2
public class SyncInformation
{
    public void HandleInsertedRecordInformation(...) {...}
    public void HandleUpdatedRecordInformation(...) {...}
    public void HandleInsertedRecordInformation(...) {...}
}
```

`Assembly2` has a reference to `Assembly1`. So `Assembly1` does not know anything about the existence of the `SyncInformation` class which need to handle the gathered information. So I have the following options to trigger this code:

1. use events and subscribe on it in `Assembly2`
   1.1. EventHandler<>
   1.2. Action<>
   1.3. Delegates
2. using dependency injection:
   `public class Assembly2.SyncInformation : Assembly1.ISyncInformation`
3. Other?

I know the performance depends on:

- OnSyncProgress

  - switch
  - using a method call, delegate, Action<> or EventHandler<>
- Implementation of SyncInformation class

I currently don't care about the implementation of the `SyncInformation` class. I am mainly focused on the `OnSyncProgress` method and how to call the `SyncInformation` methods.

So my questions are:

- **What is the most efficient approach?**
- **What is the most in-efficient approach?**
- **Is there a better way than using a switch in `OnSyncProgress`?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The sync speed can go over 50.000 records per minute. So that means my additional code need to be very lightweight otherwise it will be a huge performance penalty.

No, it won't.

50k / minute is not a significant number of method calls, unless you need to do thousands of such calls per record. This reeks of premature optimization. If we ignore intentionally badly written code and reflection-from-scratch-per-call, the ***absolute slowest*** way of calling a method is via untyped delegate `DynamicInvoke`, and that can do 50k calls in 42ms on my machine. Anything else (typed delegate `Invoke`, direct `callvirt` on a class or interface, `dynamic`, static `call` etc) will not even be measurable (as in: it will be literally 0ms for 50k calls).

You'd do better to use a profiler to see what actually matters, IMO. It will almost certainly be the "doing" code, rather than the plumbing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. '50k/minute is not a significant number of method call' I agree but I see performance differences between subscribing to the `SyncProvider.SyncProgress` event and not subscribing on it. The only thing the `OnSyncProgress` is doing (currently) 1:Add logline per 10.000 records 2:increase counters `DictionaryTableStats[tablename].RecordsDeleted++`. Are there other reasons why I see time differences? 7.000.000/46min against 7.000.000/53min? penalty of 20K/minute (Times based on test machine not on production machine. Production avg 50K/min; Test avg 150K/min)

Comment: @hwcverwe For posterity I would like to throw in a point here.  You said the OnSyncProgress is adding to a log, but did not say the cost.  In the case of low latency applications (not saying yours is, but the point is worth knowing) reducing log events helps.  If you must log you can gain benefit from binary logging (avoid parsing text).  To read the log you would then create a "Log Reader" application (which could be pretty simple).  This point was brought up about 6 months ago at a Java for electronic trading event I was at (Gil Tene, CTO Azul Systems).  The principle would hold for C#.